# difference between ContextLoader and ContextLoaderListener

Tags: java, servlets, servletcontextlistener, servlet-listeners, guice-servlet

the difference between ContextLoader and ContextLoaderListenerI am not understanding the difference. I have tried to search on google but I am not able to search. Please help me on this.

Comment: @SaviNuclear Try to be more friendly first

Answer (score 0):

Performs the actual initialization work for the root application context. Called by `ContextLoaderListener` and `ContextLoaderServlet`.

Regards a `"contextClass"` parameter at the `web.xml` context-param level, falling back to the default context class (XmlWebApplicationContext) if not found. With the default ContextLoader, a context class needs to implement ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.

Passes a `"contextConfigLocation"` context-param to the context instance, parsing it into potentially multiple file paths which can be separated by any number of commas and spaces, like `"applicationContext1.xml`, `applicationContext2.xml"`. If not explicitly specified, the context implementation is supposed to use a default location (with XmlWebApplicationContext: `

---

> Note: In case of multiple config locations, later bean definitions
>   will override ones defined in earlier loaded files, at least when
>   using one of Spring's default ApplicationContext implementations. This
>   can be leveraged to deliberately override certain bean definitions via
>   an extra XML file.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoader.html